# ASP.NET Custom Error except 404 errors,

Tags: asp.net

I have setup custom error as follows..

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is HttpUnhandledException && ex.InnerException != null)
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    if (ex != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Log(LogEventType.UnhandledException, ex);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect(MyCustomError);

}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to detect if this error is a 404 error, and then show the default 404 error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to say I'm really confused about why you're clearing whatever error happened and then redirecting to a custom error page in the first place.

Maybe change:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
Response.Redirect(MyCustomError);
//to
if (!(ex is HttpException && 404 == ((HttpException)ex).getHttpCode())){
  HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
  Response.Redirect(MyCustomError);
}
```

Otherwise don't do any of these checks and leave any file not found exceptions be. Have them be handled by your custom error handlers defined in the `web.config` via the framework.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/500.htm">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/500.htm"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

And if you aren't seeing the handling you want change the mode to "On".

If you need to throw a 404, maybe because the requested item's ID has been deleted from the DB, then throw the appropriate HttpException error.

Comment: syntax correction : if (!(ex is HttpException && 404 == ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode()))

Comment: @Ash Machine Thanks. I believe a feature just went in to allow anyone to propose edits, so, next time you can do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that requests for static files do not go through the Asp.Net framework - only files that end in .aspx do. So a request for a static file that doesn't exist will get a 404 from IIS, but not get processed by asp.net.

You could do a similar thing to as described on this page under the heading 'IIS Custom 401 Errors':

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

The gist of it is to create a custom error handler in iis that sends the user to a certain static htm file, which redirects them to your special 404 handler aspx page.

Comment: Yep but a 404 that has aspx extension?

Comment: Ah - well in that case, run it in debug mode, put a breakpoint on the Application_Error function, and have a look what you can see in the Watch window.