# Displaying Custom Error Page for "The resource cannot be found" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am coding an application in ASP.NET.

I would like to know how I can display a custom error page in case the user types the address of a page which does not exist in my project.  How can this be done please?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle server error with code 404. There is a plenty of examples over the web ([one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665005/asp-net-custom-error-except-404-errors), [three](http://forums.asp.net/t/1317222.aspx/)), but in short you can do this in web.config with the following section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

where `~/Error.html` and `~/Error404.html` are general error page and page for "Resource cannot be found" case.

Comment: I tried your solution but I must be missing something. Would you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798775/web-config-not-forwarding-to-404-error-page-on-non-aspx-pages . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the above to your webconfig

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" 
    defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/default.aspx"/>
   </customErrors>
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the MSDN documentation page for the `customErrors` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the web.config schema - the example provided is such:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```